# Create JSON file from a JavaScript object and array

Tags: javascript, json

```
function object() {
  this.arr1 = []:
  this.arr2 = []:
}
var object = new object;
object[0].arr1.push(value);
object[0].arr2.push(value);
```

How I can add an object and the array to a JSON file? I have this for example:

```
  var obj = [
    {"arr1":[ object[0].arr1[0], object[0].arr1[1] ], "arr2":[ object[0].arr2[0], object[0].arr2[1] ]}
  ];
```

I need a way to add it this way (pseudocode):

```
  var obj = [
    for (var j = 0; j < object[0].arr1.length; j++) {
      {"arr1":[ object[0].arr1[j] ], "arr2":[ object[0].arr2[0] ]}
    }
  ];
```

So that I can later use it this way when read the JSON file:

```
var obj = JSON.parse(this.response);
var a = obj[0].arr1[0];
var b = obj[0].arr1[1];
```

Comment: please add a valid data set for the start and a wanted result.

Comment: Do you want to dump data in json file?, If yes, please use node.js `fs` module to create a file and dump content into it.   Did you some format in find in which you want to save data inside file?.

Comment: I don't understand `object[0].arr1.push(value)`. `object` is an object, not an array. Did you mean `object.arr1.push(value)`?

Comment: I use JavaScript and PHP with AJAX which work's fine to set and get a JSON file. The only problem is that I want add objects with his arrays to the JSON file and read it back as explained also like this `var a = obj[0].arr1[0]`

Answer (score 0):

You don't put the `for` loop inside the array. You can use the `map()` method to iterate over an array and return a new array of objects.

```
var obj = object[0].arr1.map((val1, i) => { arr1: [val1], arr2: [object[0].arr2[i]] })
```

You can then use `JSON.stringify(obj)` to convert this to JSON, and write it to a file.